# Updating CoreData value with UIStepper effect per cell

Tags: swift, core-data, uistepper

Hopefully someone can help me... I am passing an item from the web into coredata, I am passing the values with a click of a button.. as soon as the button gets pressed then number of items and cost are immediately passed on to Coredata attributes. e.i price: 30.00, itemQuantity 1 (all well and good here per cell)

these items are then displayed on a `cellForRowAt` along side with a `UIStepper` to change the values of the item per cell. take a look:

```
var itemsArray: [ItemModel] = []

        let currentPrice = itemsArray[indexPath.row].price
        let currentQty = itemsArray[indexPath.row].itemQuantity

        
        let totalQty = currentQty + Int16(sender.value)
        let totalPrice = Double(currentPrice) * sender.value


        itemsArray[indexPath.row].setValue(totalPrice, forKey: "price")
        itemsArray[indexPath.row].setValue(totalQty, forKey: "itemQuantity")

        let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print("Failed to save main context: \(error)")
        }
```

Theoretically this would work just find.. and it does! if I don't use Coredata and just plain UI...
But since I am using CoreData... here is what's actually happening (I bet you can already tell): I am re-using the `itemsArray` which initial value per item is already 30.00, so when I multiply the `price` with a the new `sender.value` now equals to `2` i'll get 60.00 which is great but `NOW the price in coredata is 60 and new itemQuantity is 2` so when i click the + on the Stepper it all gets multiplied now three times the updated value, so it all gets messed up... because Im updating the values with the same `previously-updated-values`.. so.. yea.. I'm stuck : / How can I make this right?

Comment: Don’t update the price attribute (at least not as a result of the stepper).  Think of it as the unit price (ie. the cost of a single item).  If you need the total price, just calculate it on the fly as price*itemQuantity.

Comment: You need one price (per unit) attribute and one (total) cost attribute, or a separate product entity that holds the price.

Comment: Great advise.. thank you both, I was able to get it resolved with y'alls help